# "Garbage" IP address with colons in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for some clients

Tags: php, cron, ip-address, ipv6

I have a PHP script sitting on a server that is hit by several different machines at different times throughout the day based on cronjobs that are setup on each machine. I'd like to know the IP of the machines making the request and when it is made by a browser, the following executes successfully:

```
<?php
  ...
  echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  ...
?>
```

However, when made by CURL or any other command line tool I have attempted to use (lynx included), I end up with the following garbage:

`2701:5:4a80:7d:2ee:8eff:5e61:801d`

From the investigation I've done, this is a result of Apache not populating the `$_SERVER` variable for requests received that are made from the command line.

[REMOTE ADDR Issue with Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999352/remote-addr-issue-with-cron-job)

Anyone know of a way to get command line requests to play nice with the `$_SERVER` variable or should I go down another route?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not garbage, that is the correct remote address.  Someone used IPv6 to access your server.

Comment: My bad :-\ Any idea how to get the associated IPv4 address?

Comment: @TMan, It's not possible.  IPv4 and IPv6 don't necessarily have to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help! I'm guessing I would have to force IPv4 on the client computer to get the address I'm looking for then?

Comment: check [the accepted answer of this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555591/how-to-convert-an-address-from-ipv4-to-ipv6) for help on checking IPv4 against IPv6 addresses... it's a tricky business to say at least

Comment: For anything you develop now the safest way forward is to support both IPv4 and IPv6. You will encounter both of them at some point in time, and adding IPv6 support afterwards is so much more work...